# Proving at boolean algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra

Must prove that 
$$(X+Y
)=X+(X.Y')$$

i tried a lot of ways, using logic things and expanding this things, but cant reach the Y.
$$(X+Y
)=(X+X).(X+Y')$$

Whats the possible prove to this?

Comment: You can't prove something if it isn't true.

Comment: @dfeuer my teacher made this exercise...

Comment: Let $X = 0$ and $Y = 1$. Then $X + Y = 0 + 1 = 1$, but $X + (X \cdot Y') = 0 + (0 \cdot 0) = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should go like this:
\begin{align*}
X + Y &= (X + Y) \cdot 1 = (X + Y) \cdot (X + X') = XX + XX' + YX + YX' \\
&= X + 0 + XY + X'Y = X + XY + X'Y = X(1+Y) + X'Y = X \cdot 1 + X'Y \\
&= X + X'Y.
\end{align*}

Comment: i need $$X+XY'$$ not $$X+X'Y$$. Probably my teacher made a mistake, because all your logic is correct...

Comment: I wrote you in the comments why what you want isn't true and, hence, it cannot be proven.

Comment: Notice that $X+XY' = X(1+Y') = X$, so the value of $Y$ has no effect on your right hand side, while it does have so on the left hand side.